# reading and writing on memory process on linux

Tags: c, memory, process, operating-system

I wrote a small programm that read and write the memory of a process but I can't understand why it doesn't work.
that's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
pid_t pid=3169;
char mem_file_name[2048];
 int mem_fd;
 int offset=0;
 char buf[1005128];

sprintf(mem_file_name, "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
mem_fd = open(mem_file_name, O_RDWR,S_IRWXU);
printf("1 %s\n",strerror(errno));
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
printf("2 %s\n",strerror(errno));
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
printf("3 %s\n",strerror(errno));
lseek(mem_fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
printf("4 %s\n",strerror(errno));
read(mem_fd, buf, _SC_PAGE_SIZE);
printf("5 %s\n",strerror(errno));
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
printf("6 %s\n",strerror(errno));
printf("%s\n",buf );
}
```

that's my output:

```
1 Success
2 Success
3 Success
4 Success
5 Input/output error
6 Input/output error
```

I compiled with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c
```

and I run with root permission

```
sudo ./a.out
```

on this example I only try to read from a process, but it doesn't work.
My idea is to dump the memory of a process, but I don't know why I can't read.

ps I know that there are some tools that can dump the memory of a process, but I want to create a small programm for exercise.

Comment: To begin with, for most system calls the value of `errno` is *undefined* unless the previous function actually failed. And when they fail they will indicate it with a specific return value (usually `-1`), you can't use `errno` to check if a function failed as its value is (as mentioned) *undefined*. You need to read the documentation (like [the manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/)) of the functions you use.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that goes wrong with your code.

Your main problem is that you are trying to read from offset 0, which is the process address 0x00000000 which is not mapped to your process.

```
int offset=0;
...
lseek(mem_fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
```

it is like reading from your memory at address zero:

```
int offset=0;
char* p = 0x0;
printf("%d data",p[offset]);
```

You can only read memory through /proc/PID/mem at offsets which are valid and mapped addresses in your process.

For example, if you want to read you `buf` variable's memory through this API you can read it by seeking to its address:

```
lseek(mem_fd, (off_t)buf, SEEK_SET); /* note that on 64 bit you need to use lseek64 and off64_t */
read(mem_fd, buf, _SC_PAGE_SIZE); /* this should work */
```

Notes:

- PID should not be hard coded, either you read it from `getpid` or you use `/proc/self/mem`
- There is no point in opening the file descriptor for writing (the proc API is read only)
- Suggest you reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html as well

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the output is the same so it doesn't seems to work. By setting the offset to 0 I intended to read from the start of the process. I thought it was right since "The lseek() function repositions the offset of the open file associated
       with the file descriptor fd" from the manual

Comment: dario, please keep in mind that `/proc/PID/mem` is not a regular file! Just as the memory space of your process in not a continuous stream of data. This is an interface to read the memory as a file like object but the underlying mechanism is not really changes.
If you mean by "start of the process" the lowest address mapped into your process space then you need to find out what it is (I suggest looking at `/proc/PID/maps`).